# Why has the PowerCollections C# library recently declined in popularity?

Tags: c#, api, libraries

I just looked at the statistics for the [PowerCollections](http://powercollections.codeplex.com/stats) C# library and noticed a sharp decrease in quantity of downloads.

What may be the cause? Is there something better I should be using?

Comment: I don't see the "sharp decrease"? I see a steady decline since about 2008, but given that the library has had no updates since 2007, that doesn't seem surprising...

Comment: @Dean: I've always been a bit puzzled by this attitude.  Collection classes don't go bad just because the year has changed; it's not like they have an expiration date.

Comment: @Robert: no, but a lack of activity would make me think twice about using it: is anybody around in case I run into a problem? Look at their issue tracker: people are raising issues and nobody is even looking at them, apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any updates since 2007. That alone will keep people away.

I also suspect as we've gotten LINQ since it first came out, there's not a lot of folks looking for collections libraries anymore.

Comment: I don't think it's LINQ - more like the built-in collections have eclipsed PowerCollections in their level of sophistication (i.e. `HashSet<T>` and `System.Collections.Concurrent`).  There are only a handful of very niche classes in PowerCollections now that aren't already offered in the standard .NET library.

Comment: @Aaronaught If they're aimed at very narrow niches, it's possible that the people who needed them in the first place are already/still using the library, but there's limited "new blood".